# What is it called when a song ending fades out while repeating a theme

Tags: composition, terminology

I find it very pleasant when a song (mostly progressive rock songs, in my case) ends by looping through a somewhat repeating theme before fading out.

Good examples would be:

- Gentle Giant - [Three Friends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtVA9T9pmew) (from "Three Friends" album)
- Dream Theater - [Scarred](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6SjyRLKy70) (from "Awake" album)

(I am sure there are dozens of other examples but these two are very representative).

The question is: regarding compositional structure, is there a specific name to describe that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a Repeat and Fade.  It's hardly a compositional structure, more a cop-out for having not being able to think of a good ending :-)

Comment: Actually that is completely wrong. Fading out is a very strong psychological device. Surely you are not suggesting that many of the greatest pop composers that fade out their material are simply taking an easy way out? After all, They can't fade them out life and have to play and ending... why wouldn't they just do in the recording then?

Comment: Absolutely — a studio fade can be quite effective. That said, you can do a fade when performing live, but it's usually used quite differently than what a studio fade would be.

Comment: Seems to me like the "cop-out" comment was meant as a joke, especially given the use of the smiley.

Comment: Earliest example I know of a fade-out:  "The Planets" by Gustave Holst, 1916.  In a live performance, the chorus is off-stage and the door is slowly and silently closed.  Holst didn't give the effect a name, as far as I know.

Comment: I accepted the answer because even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conclusion_(music)#Repeat_and_fade) mentions the term, but I'm still unsure if the cop-out part was ironic or not ;-P

Comment: @AbstractDissonance: Why they'd do it in the studio recording if it's not possible live – well, live endings needn't be very sophisticated, often it's just a lot of repeating the last chorus (which may be great live when everybody sings along, but can easily get boring on a recording) followed by some kind of cued ritardando to the last chord, which rock bands tend to hold a couple of seconds with much guitar-flailing and drum filling. That wouldn't work well on the radio, hence the easy way out of fading away during the repetitions.

Comment: @MarkLutton I suppose a rock band could slowly load all their gear on a trolley and move it away from the audience?

Comment: @leftaroundabout But if an ending works live then it should also work on a recording. The point is, that there is more of a "fade because we couldn't come up with an ending". As you said, it is very easy to come up with an ending... hence fading is not because of a "cop out"... which was my point.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance The drummer could stop playing and the guitars could just gradually lower the volume on their amps.

Comment: @MarkLutton lol, that's not a fade of the music though. That is just a ringing out. That happens anyways. Guitars and other instruments naturally fade out when not being played.  While they could lower the guitars and use a volume pedal to slowly reduce the amplitude, again, that is not a "studio fade".  Guitar sound different at different volumes. Also, most guitarist use a whole host of pedals including compressors and natural OD of the amp and sometimes noise gates. These tend to make it impossible to play at low enough volumes.

Comment: At most, you could have the sound engineer lower the "masters" and make everyone go direct in so he has full control(except for acoustic instruments).  This is about as close as you can get to a true studio fade(since that is effectively what happens).

Comment: The 'cop-out' was only partly a jest.  A RTF can be effective on a recording.  It's horribly weak in live performance.

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned in some other posts it is also called a vamp.

Comment: A vamp is more typically a repeated section waiting for a cue in order to carry on.   'Vamp until ready' is frequently seen in theatre music.   I've never seen 'Vamp and fade'. 
'Vamp' also refers to a type of 'oom-pah' piano part.  Sort of the equivalent of 'just strumming' on a guitar.
That's probably enough things for 'vamp' to mean.  Let's allow a Repeat and Fade to be called just that.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same question, here are a couple answers I found on Wikipedia.

*al niente*: to nothing; fading to silence.

*perdendo* or *perdendosi*: losing volume, fading into nothing, dying away

Answer (score 0):

Smorzando
[smort-SAN-do]

1.

(music, especially as a direction) in a way that dies away.

2.

(adjective, of music) dying away.